# iPhone:Show splash screen from Documents folder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, splash-screen

In my app, I need to display a splash screen.I collect the image from URL and saved it as `Default.png` in documents folder.

I successfully saved the image and collected the path.

My problem is that it is not displayed. I don't get any errors and in the log I got correct path too.

This is my code:

```
 NSString *workSpacePath=[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Default.png"];
    imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imgView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:workSpacePath]];    

    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

I got correct path in `workSpacePath`.

Comment: At what stage of the application lifecycle are you doing this?  Does `self.view` exist yet?

Comment: @nitin how u save ur file in document folder. can u tell me?

Comment: **Splash Screen cannot be displayed from Documents Directory. It has to be in Application Bundle.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't overwrite your image with the `[UIImage imageNamed:]` method. This method only works for images that are part of your bundle. It will return nil for the path in your documents directory. And because of that you set `imgView.image` nil. Which means, remove the image.

this should work:

```
NSString *workSpacePath=[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Default.png"];
imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
imgView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:workSpacePath]];    
//imgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:workSpacePath];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

But you can't replace the "real" splash screen. You can however show a different image after the original splash screen disappeared.

Comment: How could I add the image in documents folder to application bundle?

Comment: Is there any way to show splash screen which is parsed from web server?

Comment: not as "real" splash screen. You can however show whatever image you like after the original splash screen (the default image you add to your Xcode project) has disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

The "Splashscreen" is in the image normally named `Default.png` and is in the app bundle.
Since you are not allowed to change the contents of the app bundle you can not change the "splashscreen" for your app.

Comment: How could I add the image in documents folder to application bundle?

Comment: You can't. Since you can't alter the contents of the app bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Default.png should be bundled within application bundle. It can not be loaded through external path like you required i.e. from documents directory path.

One custom solution is that you should create your view as splash page which will act as splash screen and disappear after certain amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

the way you are doing the thing seems like you are just trying to show an image within imageview - i'm not concerned with replacing the default splash screen image as you cannot do it but for you, you should only do :

```
imgView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:workSpacePath]];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```